# Ui accordion js all close

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, tabs, accordion

can anyone help me with this js code? 
I want all accordion close. I read all answer but your method doesn't work.
Can anyone correct this code for all tab closed?

```
* Copyright (c) 2012 AUTHORS.txt; Licensed MIT, GPL */
(function(a,b){a.widget("ui.accordion",{options:{active:0,animated:"slide",autoHeight:!0,clearStyle:!1,collapsible:!1,event:"click",fillSpace:!1,header:"> li > :first-child,> :not(li):even",icons:{header:"ui-icon-triangle-1-e",headerSelected:"ui-icon-triangle-1-s"},navigation:!1,navigationFilter:function(){return this.href.toLowerCase()===location.href.toLowerCase()}},_create:function(){var b=this,c=b.options;b.running=0,b.element.addClass("ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset").children("li").addClass("ui-accordion-li-fix"),b.headers=b.element.find(c.header).addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all").bind("mouseenter.accordion",function(){if(c.disabled)return;a(this).addClass("ui-state-hover")}).bind("mouseleave.accordion",function(){if(c.disabled)return;a(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover")}).bind("focus.accordion",function(){if(c.disabled)return;a(this).addClass("ui-state-focus")}).bind("blur.accordion",function(){if(c.disabled)return;a(this).removeClass("ui-state-focus")}),b.headers.next().addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");if(c.navigation){var d=b.element.find("a").filter(c.navigationFilter).eq(0);if(d.length){var e=d.closest(".ui-accordion-header");e.length?b.active=e:b.active=d.closest(".ui-accordion-content").prev()}}b.active=b._findActive(b.active||c.active).addClass("ui-state-default ui-state-active").toggleClass("ui-corner-all").toggleClass("ui-corner-top"),b.active.next().addClass("ui-accordion-content-active"),b._createIcons(),b.resize(),b.element.attr("role","tablist"),b.headers.attr("role","tab").bind("keydown.accordion",function(a){return b._keydown(a)}).next().attr("role","tabpanel"),b.headers.not(b.active||"").attr({"aria-expanded":"false","aria-selected":"false",tabIndex:-1}).next().hide(),b.active.length?b.active.attr({"aria-expanded":"true","aria-selected":"true",tabIndex:0}):b.headers.eq(0).attr("tabIndex",0),a.browser.safari||b.headers.find("a").attr("tabIndex",-1),c.event&&b.headers.bind(c.event.split(" ").join(".accordion ")+".accordion",function(a){b._clickHandler.call(b,a,this),a.preventDefault()})},_createIcons:function(){var b=this.options;b.icons&&(a("<span></span>").addClass("ui-icon "+b.icons.header).prependTo(this.headers),this.active.children(".ui-icon").toggleClass(b.icons.header).toggleClass(b.icons.headerSelected),this.element.addClass("ui-accordion-icons"))},_destroyIcons:function(){this.headers.children(".ui-icon").remove(),this.element.removeClass("ui-accordion-icons")},destroy:function(){var b=this.options;this.element.removeClass("ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset").removeAttr("role"),this.headers.unbind(".accordion").removeClass("ui-accordion-header ui-accordion-disabled ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-active ui-state-disabled ui-corner-top").removeAttr("role").removeAttr("aria-expanded").removeAttr("aria-selected").removeAttr("tabIndex"),this.headers.find("a").removeAttr("tabIndex"),this._destroyIcons();var c=this.headers.next().css("display","").removeAttr("role").removeClass("ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content ui-accordion-content-active ui-accordion-disabled ui-state-disabled");return(b.autoHeight||b.fillHeight)&&c.css("height",""),a.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this)},_setOption:function(b,c){a.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this,arguments),b=="active"&&this.activate(c),b=="icons"&&(this._destroyIcons(),c&&this._createIcons()),b=="disabled"&&this.headers.add(this.headers.next())[c?"addClass":"removeClass"]("ui-accordion-disabled ui-state-disabled")},_keydown:function(b){if(this.options.disabled||b.altKey||b.ctrlKey)return;var c=a.ui.keyCode,d=this.headers.length,e=this.headers.index(b.target),f=!1;switch(b.keyCode){case c.RIGHT:case c.DOWN:f=this.headers[(e+1)%d];break;case c.LEFT:case c.UP:f=this.headers[(e-1+d)%d];break;case c.SPACE:case c.ENTER:this._clickHandler({target:b.target},b.target),b.preventDefault()}return f?(a(b.target).attr("tabIndex",-1),a(f).attr("tabIndex",0),f.focus(),!1):!0},resize:function(){var b=this.options,c;if(b.fillSpace){if(a.browser.msie){var d=this.element.parent().css("overflow");this.element.parent().css("overflow","hidden")}c=this.element.parent().height(),a.browser.msie&&this.element.parent().css("overflow",d),this.headers.each(function(){c-=a(this).outerHeight(!0)}),this.headers.next().each(function(){a(this).height(Math.max(0,c-a(this).innerHeight()+a(this).height()))}).css("overflow","auto")}else b.autoHeight&&(c=0,this.headers.next().each(function(){c=Math.max(c,a(this).height("").height())}).height(c));return this},activate:function(a){this.options.active=a;var b=this._findActive(a)[0];return this._clickHandler({target:b},b),this},_findActive:function(b){return b?typeof b=="number"?this.headers.filter(":eq("+b+")"):this.headers.not(this.headers.not(b)):b===!1?a([]):this.headers.filter(":eq(0)")},_clickHandler:function(b,c){var d=this.options;if(d.disabled)return;if(!b.target){if(!d.collapsible)return;this.active.removeClass("ui-state-active ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-all").children(".ui-icon").removeClass(d.icons.headerSelected).addClass(d.icons.header),this.active.next().addClass("ui-accordion-content-active");var e=this.active.next(),f={options:d,newHeader:a([]),oldHeader:d.active,newContent:a([]),oldContent:e},g=this.active=a([]);this._toggle(g,e,f);return}var h=a(b.currentTarget||c),i=h[0]===this.active[0];d.active=d.collapsible&&i?!1:this.headers.index(h);if(this.running||!d.collapsible&&i)return;var j=this.active,g=h.next(),e=this.active.next(),f={options:d,newHeader:i&&d.collapsible?a([]):h,oldHeader:this.active,newContent:i&&d.collapsible?a([]):g,oldContent:e},k=this.headers.index(this.active[0])>this.headers.index(h[0]);this.active=i?a([]):h,this._toggle(g,e,f,i,k),j.removeClass("ui-state-active ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-all").children(".ui-icon").removeClass(d.icons.headerSelected).addClass(d.icons.header),i||(h.removeClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-state-active ui-corner-top").children(".ui-icon").removeClass(d.icons.header).addClass(d.icons.headerSelected),h.next().addClass("ui-accordion-content-active"));return},_toggle:function(b,c,d,e,f){var g=this,h=g.options;g.toShow=b,g.toHide=c,g.data=d;var i=function(){if(!g)return;return g._completed.apply(g,arguments)};g._trigger("changestart",null,g.data),g.running=c.size()===0?b.size():c.size();if(h.animated){var j={};h.collapsible&&e?j={toShow:a([]),toHide:c,complete:i,down:f,autoHeight:h.autoHeight||h.fillSpace}:j={toShow:b,toHide:c,complete:i,down:f,autoHeight:h.autoHeight||h.fillSpace},h.proxied||(h.proxied=h.animated),h.proxiedDuration||(h.proxiedDuration=h.duration),h.animated=a.isFunction(h.proxied)?h.proxied(j):h.proxied,h.duration=a.isFunction(h.proxiedDuration)?h.proxiedDuration(j):h.proxiedDuration;var k=a.ui.accordion.animations,l=h.duration,m=h.animated;m&&!k[m]&&!a.easing[m]&&(m="slide"),k[m]||(k[m]=function(a){this.slide(a,{easing:m,duration:l||700})}),k[m](j)}else h.collapsible&&e?b.toggle():(c.hide(),b.show()),i(!0);c.prev().attr({"aria-expanded":"false","aria-selected":"false",tabIndex:-1}).blur(),b.prev().attr({"aria-expanded":"true","aria-selected":"true",tabIndex:0}).focus()},_completed:function(a){this.running=a?0:--this.running;if(this.running)return;this.options.clearStyle&&this.toShow.add(this.toHide).css({height:"",overflow:""}),this.toHide.removeClass("ui-accordion-content-active"),this.toHide.length&&(this.toHide.parent()[0].className=this.toHide.parent()[0].className),this._trigger("change",null,this.data)}}),a.extend(a.ui.accordion,{version:"1.8.21",animations:{slide:function(b,c){b=a.extend({easing:"swing",duration:300},b,c);if(!b.toHide.size()){b.toShow.animate({height:"show",paddingTop:"show",paddingBottom:"show"},b);return}if(!b.toShow.size()){b.toHide.animate({height:"hide",paddingTop:"hide",paddingBottom:"hide"},b);return}var d=b.toShow.css("overflow"),e=0,f={},g={},h=["height","paddingTop","paddingBottom"],i,j=b.toShow;i=j[0].style.width,j.width(j.parent().width()-parseFloat(j.css("paddingLeft"))-parseFloat(j.css("paddingRight"))-(parseFloat(j.css("borderLeftWidth"))||0)-(parseFloat(j.css("borderRightWidth"))||0)),a.each(h,function(c,d){g[d]="hide";var e=(""+a.css(b.toShow[0],d)).match(/^([\d+-.]+)(.*)$/);f[d]={value:e[1],unit:e[2]||"px"}}),b.toShow.css({height:0,overflow:"hidden"}).show(),b.toHide.filter(":hidden").each(b.complete).end().filter(":visible").animate(g,{step:function(a,c){c.prop=="height"&&(e=c.end-c.start===0?0:(c.now-c.start)/(c.end-c.start)),b.toShow[0].style[c.prop]=e*f[c.prop].value+f[c.prop].unit},duration:b.duration,easing:b.easing,complete:function(){b.autoHeight||b.toShow.css("height",""),b.toShow.css({width:i,overflow:d}),b.complete()}})},bounceslide:function(a){this.slide(a,{easing:a.down?"easeOutBounce":"swing",duration:a.down?1e3:200})}}})})(jQuery);;
```

Comment: You'd be better off reading the docs here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion

Comment: yes...but if i change active & false...not change everything

Comment: Minified code is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

There is the code what you need to do with your accordion element:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false
   });
});
```

With `collapsible: true` ([documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-collapsible)) we set your accordion to allow us to close sections, and with `active: false` ([documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active)) we said to accordion "We don't want any section open at the beginning"

EDIT:

I think that you should change the code right here:

```
(function(a,b){a.widget("ui.accordion",
{options:{active:0,animated:"slide",autoHeight:!0,
clearStyle:!1,collapsible:0,[...]
```

Just changing `collapsible:!1` to `collapsible:0`. The rest of the code must stay the same (I don't know what it doing). This piece of code is at the beginning.

Comment: ok...for a normal accordion ok...it's easy...but in my situation, i don't understand where are this code or where I need to put this setting...

Comment: i change..but not works...this is test site: www.peacockdesign.it/wordpress.... look the accordion on the right...thx so much

Comment: @Morver16 Ok, I saw your web. I recommend you to use http://jsbeautifier.org/ Copy & paste your code on the textbox and press "Beautify Javascript or HTML". Now, you're able to see the code formated. Anyways, I'm going to try to help you. Give me some time. I will edit my answer later :)